# How to loop by specific step

Tags: python

I have a nested loop data=

```
[[1,43,344,546],[2,34,45,565]....[10,1,1,1],

[1,15,111,151],[2,152,28,19]....[10,2,2,2],

[1,21,45,1647],[2,288,65,90]....[10,3,3,3]
                      .....]
```

so basically, all the inside lists can be grouped by 10lists with the first element always starting from 1 to 10. taking the every 10th list as a key, so I want to calculate a newlist by subtracting every list's number by the 10th list accordingly, for example

```
[[1,43-1,344-2,546-3],   [2,34-1,45-2,565-3]....   [10,1,2,3],

[1,15-21,111-22,151-23],[2,152-21,28-22,19-23]....[10,21,22,23],

[1,21-31,45-32,1647-33],[2,288-31,65-32,90-33]....[10,31,32,33]

.....]
```

My code seems don't work, can someone plz help with this? thanks

```
line = 0
    while line <= (len(data) - 10):
          for i in range(line, line + 10):
               temp = data[i]
               if temp[0] == 10: #find the every 10 th keys and store them to x, y, z
               x = temp[1]
               y = temp[2]
               z = temp[3]
               break

          for sublist in data:
             sublist[1] = sublist[1] - x# assign new elements to original list data
             sublist[2] = sublist[2] - y
             sublist[3] = sublist[3] - z
line += 10
return data
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do what you want

```
from pprint import pprint

def next_mul(n):
    "returns next multiple of 10 greater than n"
    return n + (10 - n % 10)

# sample data 
data = [[i for i in range(4)] for i in range(20)]

for i in range(len(data)):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        continue
    data[i-1][1:] = [k-l for k,l in zip(data[next_mul(i)-1][1:], data[i-1][1:])]

pprint(data)
```

Output (originally every sublist of `data` was just `[0, 1, 2, 3]`):

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if there are any questions/concerns!